# Groupby With Multi Index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to build a data frame like the one below using pandas where Asum only gets a value if there are intervals 1 and 3 on that day.  The closest I've gotten to something working is using this:

```
 df['ASum']=df.groupby(level=['DateTime'])['A'].sum()
```

But when I run it, it returns NaN all the way down ASum.  Any ideas on how to do this are appreciated.

```
                     A         B      ASum
DateTime   INT                                                                 
2016-07-05 3      4700.0     4700.0   0
2016-07-06 1      5906.0     6830.0   0 
           3      1090.0     1090.0   6996 
2016-07-07 1      7969.0     5273.0   0 
           3      1971.0     1971.0   9940 
2016-07-08 1      3296.0     2764.0   0
           3      1179.0     1179.0   4475 
2016-07-11 1      4993.0     5798.0   0 
           3      1325.0     1325.0   6318
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on unstacking the `INT` level, taking the sum and stacking it back.

```
import pandas as pd

midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['2016-07-05', '2016-07-06', '2016-07-07',
                              '2016-07-08', '2016-07-11'], [1, 3]],
                     labels=[[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                             [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
                     names=['DateTime', 'INT'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4700.0, 5906.0, 1090.0, 7969.0, 1971.0,
                         3296.0, 1179.0, 4993.0, 1325.0],
                   'B': [4700.0, 6830.0, 1090.0, 5273.0, 1971.0,
                         2764.0, 1179.0, 5798.0, 1325.0]},
                 index=midx)

df = df.unstack(level='INT')
df[('Asum', 3)] = df['A'].sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
df = df.stack(level='INT').fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     A       B    Asum
DateTime   INT                        
2016-07-05 3    4700.0  4700.0     0.0
2016-07-06 1    5906.0  6830.0     0.0
           3    1090.0  1090.0  6996.0
2016-07-07 1    7969.0  5273.0     0.0
           3    1971.0  1971.0  9940.0
2016-07-08 1    3296.0  2764.0     0.0
           3    1179.0  1179.0  4475.0
2016-07-11 1    4993.0  5798.0     0.0
           3    1325.0  1325.0  6318.0
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto! this works quite nicely! I've been playing around with trying to get this to work with .pct_change as well but haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['ASum'] = 0   # the new column MUST be defined ahead

for idx,data in df.groupby(level=['DateTime']):
    if all(x in data.index.get_level_values('INT') for x in [1,3]):
        df.loc[idx,'ASum'].iloc[-1] = data['A'].sum()  # adds the sum to the last row in the group only
```

Which results:

```
                   A  ASum
DateTime   INT            
2016-07-05 3    4700     0
2016-07-06 1    5906     0
           3    1090  6996
2016-07-07 1    7967     0
           3    1971  9938
2016-07-08 1    3296     0
           3     119  3415
2016-07-11 1    4993     0
           3    1325  6318
```

**Or** if you want the sum to appear where `INT==3` (and not necessarily on the last line):

```
df['ASum'] = 0

for idx,data in df.groupby(level=['DateTime']):
    if all(x in data.index.get_level_values('INT') for x in [1,3]):
        df.loc[(idx,3),'ASum'] = data['A'].sum()  # << changed this line only
```

(Until I'll come up with some aggregative solution)